# What is the syntax to update multiple heterogeneous keys using the Redis JSON package for Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, json, redis

I have a Node.JS app that use the Redis JSON NPM package.  I know I can update multiple keys using a JsonPath pattern like the Redis JSON docs show:

```
redis> JSON.SET doc $ '{"f1": {"a":1}, "f2":{"a":2}}'
OK
redis> JSON.SET doc $..a 3
OK
redis> JSON.GET doc
"{\"f1\":{\"a\":3},\"f2\":{\"a\":3}}"
```

But that only works if you are updating keys with a common name, and the path pattern ("$..a") matches multiple keys.  Is there a way to update multiple keys with the same SET command but using a list of independent paths?  For example something akin to:

```js
            await self.redisClient.json.set(
                redisKey,
                ["$.key_1", "$.key_2", "$.key_3"],
                valueToAssign,
                {
                    NX: true
                }
            )
```

Where the value "valueToAssign" would be assigned to the top level keys: "key_1", "key_2", and key_3" in the above hypothetical example?  The above example uses the `NX` option so I would want the assignments to be made only if for those keys that do not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are under the same parent, you could use the JSONPath `union` operator (using comma), for example (using CLI), setting value of both `$.a` and `$.b`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET test $ '{"a":10, "b":20, "c":30}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET test '$.["a","b"]'
"[10,20]"
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET test '$.["a","b"]' 50
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET test $
"[{\"a\":50,\"b\":50,\"c\":30}]"
```

Other than that, currently, you can call multiple `JSON.SET` in a single transaction using `MULTI` and `EXEC`.

See also https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/issues/414

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that try and see if the Redis JSON NPM package supports the "union" JsonPath syntax.